# I am trying to draw shape using servlet with the following code but the image is not being displayed

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to draw shape using servlet with the following code but the image is not being displayed. The code words fine when using JSP and servlet separately but when I put the entire code in Servlet it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class CreateShapes
     */
    @WebServlet("/CreateShapes")
    public class CreateShapes extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        HttpSession sessionvar;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // response.getWriter().append("Served at:
        // ").append(request.getContextPath());
        // response.setContentType("text/html");
        ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
        sos.println("<html><body>");
        sos.println("<form method='get' action='CreateShapes'>");
        sos.println(
                "<input type='submit' name='btn' value='Circle'><br><input type='submit' name='btn' value='Square'><br><input type='submit' name='btn' value='Rectangle'>");
        sos.println("</form></body></html>");

        String shapeselected = request.getParameter("btn");

        if (shapeselected.length() > 0) {
            sessionvar = request.getSession();
            sessionvar.setAttribute("selectedshape", shapeselected);
            sos.flush();

        }

        // sos = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        sos.println("session value\t" + sessionvar.getAttribute("selectedshape").toString());
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        // g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        // g.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

        if (sessionvar.getAttribute("selectedshape").toString().equals("Circle")) {

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(30, 30, 150, 150);
            g.dispose();
            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpeg", sos);
        } else if (sessionvar.getAttribute("selectedshape").equals("Square")) {

            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(80, 80, 100, 100);
            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpeg", sos);
        } else {

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(80, 80, 200, 150);
            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpeg", sos);
        }
        sos.flush();
        // sos.close();

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code that works, to understand, what you want to achieve. **Anyway**, you cannot output both HTML **and** image from one servlet method (actually, Michael Akerman's answer below is pretty accurate, given the ambiguity of the original question, I do not understand why someone downvoted it).

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CreateShapes
 */
@WebServlet("/CreateShapes")
public class CreateShapes extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType( "text/html" );
        ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();

        sos.println( "<html><body>" );
        sos.println( "<form method='post' action='CreateShapes'>" );
        sos.println( "<input type='submit' name='btn' value='Circle'><br><input type='submit' name='btn' value='Square'><br><input type='submit' name='btn' value='Rectangle'>" );
        sos.println( "</form></body></html>" );
        sos.close();
    }

    protected void doPost ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType( "image/jpeg" );
        ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage( 500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        // g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        // g.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

        String shapeselected = request.getParameter( "btn" );
        if ( shapeselected.equals( "Circle" ) )
        {
            g.setColor( Color.RED );
            g.fillOval( 30, 30, 150, 150 );
            g.dispose();
            ImageIO.write( bi, "jpeg", sos );
        }
        else
        {
            if ( shapeselected.equals( "Square" ) )
            {
                g.setColor( Color.GREEN );
                g.fillRect( 80, 80, 100, 100 );
                ImageIO.write( bi, "jpeg", sos );
            }
            else
            {
                g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
                g.fillRect( 80, 80, 200, 150 );
                ImageIO.write( bi, "jpeg", sos );
            }
        }

        sos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MichealAkerman  your answer did solve my problem to some extend but I want the buttons to remain on the screen along with the displayed shape.